# How to get text of .dat files of the zip files which are available in sub folder of one zip file in asp.net core 6.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, c#-ziparchive

my `IFormFile` zip file contains multiple folders which again contains zip files which contains .dat types files, so need to read this .dat file's text data.

I tried like below

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RequestFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
            {
                foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.Name.ToLower().Contains(".zip"))
                    {
                        MemoryStream nestedArchiveStream = new MemoryStream();

                        entry.Open().CopyTo(nestedArchiveStream);
                        
                        using (var nestedArchive = new ZipArchive(nestedArchiveStream))
                        {
                            var datFile = nestedArchive.Entries[0];

                            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datFile.ToString());
                            string strAllFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

> Error : Could not find file 'D:\project'spath\WPNN788_4_11-15-22_084023.dat'.

Comment: You're trying to read from the request's network stream, not an actual file. You can't go back and forth in a network stream. You'll have to copy the file to disk before you can decompress it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the codes `datFile.ToString()`returns the relative path.

[image]

However,the constructor of StreamReader requires the full path

[image]

And the error indicates:If you pass a relative path into the constructor,it would treate the path like:

```
var fullpath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, relativepath);
```

You could try to pass the stream instead of the path into the constructor:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datFile.Open());
```

I debugged and the result:

[image]